# Firebase parando a iteração do forEach

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo

### Objetivo:

Estou tentando fazer um array de objetos contendo 3 informações: **`id`**, **`title`** e **`imageUri`**. Porém ao pegar o valor de **`imageUri`** do firebase(*uma URL de download*), o forEach trava.

**Erro**:[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.]

**observação**: Quando eu retiro a parte do firebase(**`imageUri: firebase...`**), funciona como o esperado

> a função:

```js
    processData = ( data ) => {
        console.log('---------data recebida na processData(Main.js:70)--------\n', data)
        var localProcessedData = [];

        Object.entries(data).forEach( ([key, value]) => {
          var event = {
            id: key,
            title: Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(value, "eventTitle").value,
            imageUri: firebase.storage().ref('events/active/' + key + '/image').getDownloadURL()
          }
          localProcessedData.push(event);
        })

        this.setState({
          processedData: localProcessedData,
          eventsDataIsLoaded: true,
        })
      }
```

> o tipo de dado que a função recebe como parâmetro:

```js
     Object {
      "-M-I83aV9t1fezOsBn17": Object {
        "active": true,
        "created": "2020-02-05T02:18:30.772Z",
        "description": "Olimpiadas Inter Atletica",
        "eventTitle": "oia",
        "location": "Uberlandia",
        "owner": "p87xn6x8DZTwb6qyTadhkk3UxJV2",
        "price": "130",
        "startDate": "15",
        "time": "14",
        "updated": "2020-02-05T02:18:30.772Z",
      },
      "-M-KlUH-zQhnIhb6wMH8": Object {
        "active": true,
        "created": "2020-02-05T14:34:20.399Z",
        "description": "Cia 2020",
        "eventTitle": "Cia",
        "location": "Uberlandia",
        "owner": "p87xn6x8DZTwb6qyTadhkk3UxJV2",
        "price": "130340",
        "startDate": "15",
        "time": "14",
        "updated": "2020-02-05T14:34:20.399Z",
      }
    }
```

> Meu objetivo é formatar esse dado e transforma-lo num array desse modo:

```js
    Array [
      Object {
        "id": "-M-I83aV9t1fezOsBn17",
        "title": "oia",
        "imageUri": "url da imagem"
      },
      Object {
        "id": "-M-KlUH-zQhnIhb6wMH8",
        "title": "Cia",
        "imageUri": "url da imagem"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Dá uma lha aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42266462/react-native-json-stringify-cannot-serialize-cyclical-structures

Comment: @LeAndrade eu tinha lido isso mais cedo mas nao entendi muito bem

Comment: a função ```getDownloadUrl``` não retorna uma Promise? ou eu estou enganado?

Comment: @LeandroSimões sim

Comment: Então, nesse caso vc teria que executar essa função, obter o resultado dela, através do `.then` e só depois, com o resultado em mão, continua a função e cria o objeto `event`. Do jeito que está fazendo ali, a propriedade `imageUri` do objeto `event` não é a url em si, e sim uma Promise não "resolvida", não sei se deu pra entender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi fazendo a função ficar *async*:

````js
Object.entries(data).forEach( async ([key, value]) => {
  var event = {
     id: key,
     title: Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(value, "eventTitle").value,
     imageUri: await firebase.storage().ref('events/active/' + key + '/image').getDownloadURL()
  }
  localProcessedData.push(event);
})```
````